# Problem with the user on my achievements on EasyAdmin3 and symfony5

Tags: symfony, symfony5, easyadmin3

This issue is on Symfony 5. I create the admin side of my site with an EasyAdmin v3 bundle.
My problem occurs when I try to add a realization and it gives me the following error message.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXpLr.png

It says that my user cannot be null, but the concern is that I am trying to add a realization with the admin account so I would like them to take into account that I am logged in as admin and put myself the realization from this account. Below is my code My realization entity.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\RealisationRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RealisationRepository::class)
 *  @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Realisation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateRealisation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $portfolio;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $file;
    /**
     * @var File
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="Realisation",fileNameProperty="file")
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="realisations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Categorie::class, inversedBy="realisations")
     */
    private $categorie;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categorie = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateRealisation(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateRealisation;
    }

    public function setDateRealisation(?\DateTimeInterface $dateRealisation): self
    {
        $this->dateRealisation = $dateRealisation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPortfolio(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->portfolio;
    }

    public function setPortfolio(bool $portfolio): self
    {
        $this->portfolio = $portfolio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFile(): ?string
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function setFile(string $file): self
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Categorie[]
     */
    public function getCategorie(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    public function addCategorie(Categorie $categorie): self
    {
        if (!$this->categorie->contains($categorie)) {
            $this->categorie[] = $categorie;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategorie(Categorie $categorie): self
    {
        $this->categorie->removeElement($categorie);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param File $imageFile
     */
    public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;
        if(null !== $imageFile){
            $this->dateRealisation = new \DateTime();
        }
    }
}
```

My realisationCrudController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Realisation;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\BooleanField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateTimeField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ImageField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IntegerField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextEditorField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IdField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextareaField;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;

class RealisationCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Realisation::class;

    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {

        return [
            IntegerField::new('id','ID')->onlyOnIndex(),
            TextField::new('nom'),
            TextEditorField::new('description'),
            DateTimeField::new('createdAt'),
            DateTimeField::new('dateRealisation'),
            TextField::new('slug'),
           BooleanField::new('portfolio'),
            TextareaField ::new('imageFile')
                ->setFormType(VichFileType::class)
                ->setLabel('Image'),


        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always i) find a title that summarizes your question and ii) include error messages as text not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want **user** to always be the user logged in creating your `Realisation` entity ?

A simple way to achieve that would be using events to automatically set the user to your logged in user.

One example would be to use an EventSubscriber:

```
class DoctrineSubscriber implements EventSubscriber

    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(
        TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
    ) {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::prePersist => 'prePersist',
        ];
    }

    public function prePersist(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
       $entity = $args->getObject();

        if ($entity instanceof Realisation) {
            $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
            if($user){
                $entity->setUser($user);
            }else{
                //throw an exception, no user logged in
            }
            
        }
    }

}
```

And don't forget to define your event subscriber in the services.yaml

```
  #services.yaml
  App\EventSubscriber\DoctrineSubscriber:
    tags:
      - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
```

Another way would be to override the createEntity method from your EasyAdmin AbstractCrudController :

```
public function createEntity(string $entityFqcn)
{
    $realisation = new Realisation();
    
    $realisation->setUser($this->getUser());

    return $realisation;
}
```